# A good way to add analytic field to access query?

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba, pivot-table

I am using Excel pivot tables to analyse recorded values in big Access tables.

For example I have table

```
mark1 | mark2 | value
x     |y      |1
w     |z      |2
t     |l      |3
```

and now I am adding a field "mymark" using access query field expression:

```
GROOPER: 
Switch(
[mark1]="x";"yes";
[mark2]="z";"no";
1=1;"dunno"
)
```

or even more complex:

```
COMPLEXGROOPER: 
Switch(
([mark1]="x" or [mark1]="r") and [mark2]<>"";"yes";
[mark2]="z" or [mark2]="zz" or left([mark2],1)="z";"no";
1=1;"dunno"
)
```

My aim is to have a data in a way like:

```
mark1 | mark2 | value| mymark
x     |y      |1     |yes
w     |z      |2     |no 
t     |l      |3     |dunno
```

and then analyse it in Excel pivot table by "mymark"

it was ok with expressions until I met a limit on a expression size in 1023 symbols.

Is there a good way to overcome this limit?

Also I tried to pack all the logic in VBA function and then use the function name in access expression. It works for making a query result inside access, but when I tried to use that query as a source for Excel pivot table data, error rises in fact that my custom vba function is undefined in expression.

Answer (score 1):

1) What about putting the grouping values in a separate table:

```
key   | value
--------------
x     | yes
y     | no
```

and `LEFT JOIN`:

```
FROM mytable
LEFT JOIN keyvalueTable ON mytable.mark = keyvalueTable.key
```

Then, to show values not in the keyvalueTable, use either `Nz` which returns the first argument if it isn't null, otherwise it returns the second argument:

```
GROUPER: Nz(keyvalueTable.value, "dunno")
```

If you can't use `Nz` in a linked Excel query, then try `Iif`:

```
GROUPER: Iif(keyvalueTable.value Is Null, "dunno", keyvalueTable.value)
```

2) Depending on your needs, you might also consider using a crosstab query within Access, instead of reading it from Excel. You can use VBA functions within a crosstab query.